# Convert gray surface image to color (according to xray color code of each material)

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, imageprocessor

I wrote a software to connect to the xray luggage inspection machine and receive the scanned images.

But these images are on a gray level and should be turned into a color photo.

Of course, the desired color photo must be with xray color code, which is different according to the category of materials.
My output data from the device is as follows:

[image]

I convert this data to an image with the following Python code:

```py
    input_arr = np.array(input) # converting the list of lists to numpy array
    input_arr_rescaled = (255.0 / input_arr.max() * (input_arr - input_arr.min())).astype(np.uint8)
    plt.imshow(input_arr) # visualization with matplotlib
    # for saving the matrix itself
    from PIL import Image
    im = Image.fromarray(input_arr_rescaled )
    im.save("image.png")
```

Sample output image:

[image]

Sample output image of xray device:

[image]

My other question is how can I delete the image of the conveyor?

Comment: So, is your question about how to add the `cmap` parameter to `plt.imshow()`? Or where to find a suitable colourmap? Or something else?

Comment: the "sample output image" looks usable, if a bit squashed/stretched. it would only need to be resized. -- either the exposure of lines varies over time or you have pixels with varying responses. "dark field subtraction" would solve the second issue (more likely). -- and I would **strongly** recommend reading the binary data (uint16 values) directly with numpy, instead of having ascii decimal numbers as an intermediate format.

Comment: @MarkSetchell, When I use plt.imshow(), it does not give me the right color. Can color information be extracted from this data? Or should I use colourmap?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz, Thanks a lot. Excuse me, I did not understand the meaning of the first part of your talk. Can you explain more? In the second part, do you mean to convert this data into binary and then generate the output image?